# Dual boot ubuntu on a hdd with Intel optane

Tags: dual-boot

I have just bought a lenovo 330s-15ikb, and would like to dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu (any version!) on it. Windows appears to run with no problem, but when I try to install ubuntu from a usb it skips the first installation type page and jumps straight to the manual repartition page, but with no partitions actually shown. Running parted -l shows nothing, but running sudo parted -l shows the existing partitions.

I have a 1tb had with a 16gb optane drive, as seems to be common in similar devices. I have seen people with similar problems suggest the problem is Intel's rst sata controller.

Ideally I would like to install ubuntu with drivers to support the optane memory. Does anyone know if/when that will be possible?

If not, has anyone successfully installed windows in ahci mode on this machine? Ive tried both the regedit method and restarting in safe mode after changing to ahci in the bios method which I've seen in various places, but neither seem to work for me.

Also, is this issue likely to affect any machine with a hdd accelerated using Intel optane?

Comment: See response from Intel. Says you can use AHCI. https://communities.intel.com/thread/121155

Answer (score 3):

You cannot dual boot the Intel optane linked HDD. This is a serious limitation and various complaints/discussions are going on the intel official forum.

However one thing you could try is Disable the (RTS/Optane), then create a separate partition for ubuntu and try dual booting. If works later the optane memory can be enabled for the remaining partition.

Comment: I can confirm disabling Optane worked for me. Although I ran into some issues when trying to re-enable it after installing Ubuntu. Heres a youtube video of someone going through this process. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2uXgbF3P2F8  https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05591811

Comment: Yes. I was able to boot ubuntu only after disabling optane.

Answer (score 0):

Same laptop model and everything here. You'll have to go into your BIOS settings and switch over to AHCI mode, but the laptop doesn't come with the AHCI drivers pre-installed. So first off you're going to have to go online and get it's drivers. Once you install that (presumably on windows), you can go back into your BIOS settings, turn off RST (disabling your optane) and switching to ACHI. After that you should be able to easily install your copy of Ubuntu onto your laptop.

If you've somehow corrupted your windows system and can't access your Windows, get a USB, download the windows system .iso file and make a bootable USB. Plug that into your system and you should be able to install a clean copy.