# Ubuntu installs but no grub and its invisible to Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, 20.04

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 as a dual-boot on my HP laptop and I can boot off my USB, OS runs fine off it and when I install, everything seems to go as expected.

After installing though, Ubuntu doesn't boot, grub doesn't appear, and when I go into Windows, there is no evidence Ubuntu tried to install itself.

My first install attempt, I tried with un-allocated space on my SSD and after installing and a reboot, the space still showed as un-allocated. It may be worth noting now I have an SSD with Intel Optane built in, and no storage manager sees the integrated 32GB.

After not getting any Ubuntu boot, I tried manually booting the grub `.efi` but there was no Ubuntu entry in my EFI partition at all.

I started trying anything I could think at this point. Tried different secure boot settings, using cmd to change the bootloader to grub, using `easyuefi` to attempt moving the efi files manually from the ISO, assigning a disk letter the install and after every attempt I'd reinstall and still get the same problems.

The closest I got was when I copied the grub efi file to my efi partition I could get a grub command line, but it wasn't detecting any OS. When I boot off the USB and try to mount my install, it fails to mount.

I'm decently savvy with Windows but my Ubuntu and Linux knowledge is pretty limited so while overall I'm at a loss of what I can try, I can give any suggestions a go.

Comment: It's ext4 so not appearing is fine, but try installing ubuntu again?

Comment: Well not appearing from explorer would be normal, the problem is disk managers like aomei and i believe windows disk manager even shows ext4 but it was showing as no formatting and no data used. I've tried installing at least 6 times now, probably more

Comment: Not showing it as formatted and no data used is also common. Did you make sure that you installed both in the same boot mode (UEFI or Legacy BIOS) and did you make sure that Ubuntu is 1st in boot sequence in firmware settings? Also does Ubuntu appear in boot options (Usually accessed through `F12`). PS: Please reply with @username or your reply may go unnoticed!

Comment: See also [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097796/dual-boot-ubuntu-on-a-hdd-with-intel-optane](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097796/dual-boot-ubuntu-on-a-hdd-with-intel-optane)