# System freezes while installing Ubuntu(dual boot)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 20.04, windows, bootloader

I installed Ubuntu 20.04, the installation went pretty well but when rebooted after removing the USB it froze at the booting phase. Then I removed Ubuntu by deleting the partition from windows and tried to install it again. But this time it freezes while selecting the "install Ubuntu" option. Sometimes it gets into the installation phase but after 2 or 3 steps it freezes again. Errors were something like "initramfs" , "PCIe bus error" and something like "nouveau" and "ACPI" don't know much.

And the boot menu still has Ubuntu as an entry which when selected takes nowhere, a blank screen.

So how can I install it without getting those errors and also get rid that boot entry of previously installed Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had this issue come up and I can tell you what did it for me. It wound up being two things.

First, I have a new laptop (HP Spectre x360) with an Intel Optane SSD. Apparently you can't dual boot with that technology active, so I had to go into my bios and disable the Intel Optane, essentially turning it back into a regular NVMe SSD. ([Dual boot ubuntu on a hdd with Intel optane](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097796/dual-boot-ubuntu-on-a-hdd-with-intel-optane))

Next, I had the same issue, where I had a former install and I cleared the partition, but in trying to reinstall, it would hang after the "Continue" button on the install window.

Apparently what was happening was that the Ubuntu entry in the EFI Bootloader was corrupted and so the installer was hanging on finding/recognizing/overwriting it. Basically, you need to mount the EFI Bootloader partition to a drive letter in windows and then delete the folder "ubuntu" which has the problematic grub2 files. Below is an example of how to fix this with command lines in Windows (remember that you need to run everything with administrator privileges). The specific commands are at the bottom of the linked page, and there are other places on the web that can tell you how to do this.

https://www.securedyou.com/how-to-delete-grub-loader-windows-10-boot-efi-partition/

In my case, the files in the "ubuntu" folder in the EFI Bootloader were corrupted, so I couldn't delete them directly, I had to run "chkdsk /f" to fix the problem, where it turned the "ubuntu" folder into a file and then I could delete that file.

After removing the "ubuntu" folder from the EFI Bootloader partition and disabling the Intel Optane in the UEFI Bios, the install went surprisingly smoothly.

Comment: Thanks ,it worked .

Comment: Now I'm facing another error. After selecting from the grub menu, it starts to boot into ubuntu , but after a few seconds it show black screen with PCIe bus error and goes on showing. What should I do now? I could boot into ubuntu only twice after this happend.

Comment: Not really sure, my semi-expertise is only dual-booting. I would try booting into a safe graphics mode, if that doesn't work, make a new question with the specific info for the PCIe bus error. Someone else in the askubuntu ecosystem probably has an answer. Glad to hear you fixed the EFI Bootloader.

Comment: Yes, I tried booting into safe graphics mode but didn't work.

Comment: I will put another question then.